# Why is my bootstrap button not getting rounded

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I am using "btn-info" class but for some reason the button is not getting rounded and designed properly. I don,t have any css for this class. I am using it inside a div which doesn't have a class and is inside a 'container' div. I get the blue color for the button and nothing more.

Comment: provide your code please

Comment: code is too huge to paste her

Comment: did you check with `border-radius`

Comment: @Tere he didn't mean the WHOLE code, just the relevant part

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to use `btn-info` together with `btn`. E.g.:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info">Info</button>
```

Comment: I had to add some css for mine: `.btn.btn-rounded { border-radius: 50px }`

Comment: @phyatt you are probably using a newer Bootstrap version, where corners are not rounded by default. The answer above is already almost 4 years old.

Answer (score 0):

It can still be usefull to someone : `rounded-circle` now can make the trick.

See  [bootsrap doc](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/utilities/borders/#radius)

`class="btn btn-sm btn-success rounded-circle"`